# laravel 5: does laravel have helper for iterate collection?

Tags: laravel, collections, flat

this is my collection sample with topless child

```
'os'    =>     id          => '1'       
              'OS'         => 'Linux',
              'lang'       => 'english',
              'short_tags' => true
               'child'
                    0 =>
                        id => '2'
                        os  => 'ubuntu'
                        'child' 
                            0 =>
                                id = '3'
                                os  => 'mint'   

                            1 =>
                                id => '4'
                                os  => 'lubuntu'    
                                    .
                                    .
                                    .
                .
                .
                .
                                .
```

how can i convert this collection to simple flat array with only "id" index?
like this

```
{id=>1, id=>2, id=>3, id=>4}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pluck()` method:

```
$collection = collect($array);
$ids = $collection->pluck('id');
```